# How to query distnict opportunity records

Tags: apex, soql

I need to display related opportunities in lead page with some requirements like order by unit potential and display only highest unit potential record of the opportunity.means I want to display distinct opportunity records

So I tried to use `Count_Distinct` but I am not able to parse query.

How can I modify the below query to get the data I want?

```
Select Id,Number_of_Units__c,Name,StageName,Type,Billing_City__c,Opp_Sic_Code__c from 
Opportunity where Billing_City__c=:cityset AND Opp_Sic_Code__c=:Sicset AND 
StageName='Closed Won' ORDER BY Number_of_Units__c Desc Limit 10
```

[image: Opportunity Map]

I need to display only two opportunities in above scenario first one and third one,opportunity test-- & Internal.Because test-- has the highest unit potential for the account Sample and internal is related to other account

Comment: can you provide an example with data what you are looking for

Comment: Do you want to get the opportunity with highest unit potential related to an account?

Comment: Yes @SfdcBat but I need to display only one opportunity from an account.

Comment: @SantanuBoral My question has been updated please check once.

Comment: check my answer, hopefully it will work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will not be direct SOQL query which can meet your requirement.

Here is the approach.

> Put `ORDER BY AccountId,Number_of_Units__c Desc` in SOQL
>
> - Since you are retrieving records in `DESC`, so highest value for an Account will be displayed first and that will be added to the map.
> - Now, next time, for the same account, if Opportunity record is coming then that will be ignored.
> - finally take the `mapAccountWithOpporty.values()` which will have Opportunity with **highest** Number_of_Units__c, perform whatever you want to do.

```
//this map holds AccountId with that Opportunity which has highest Number_of_Units__c
Map<Id, Opportunity> mapAccountWithOpporty = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();

List<Opportunity> lstOppty = [Select Id, AccountId, Number_of_Units__c,Name,StageName,Type,Billing_City__c,Opp_Sic_Code__c 
                                from Opportunity 
                                where Billing_City__c=:cityset 
                                AND Opp_Sic_Code__c=:Sicset 
                                AND StageName='Closed Won' 
                                ORDER BY AccountId,Number_of_Units__c Desc];
for(Opportunity opty:lstOppty)
{
    if(!mapAccountWithOpporty.containsKey(opty.AccountId))
    {
        mapAccountWithOpporty.put(opty.AccountId, opty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Order By is a great idea. May I ask if there is any reason for using Limit 10?

Comment: Limit is not required,  I have used your limit clause, I have removed at my updated code

Comment: Gotcha. Hope the OP finds this helpful to solve his problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return all of the fields you have in your query, you likely want to avoid aggregate queries, which is the only place you can use the `COUNT_DISTINCT` function. Any such attempt would yield:

> Field must be grouped or aggregated: ...

You can use post-processing to get the count of distinct `AccountId` values using a `Set`. Don't forget to add this field to your query!

```
List<Opportunity> records = [/*query*/];
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Opportunity record : records)
    accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
Integer uniqueAccountIdCount = accountIds.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by two ways.

1) `Apex : Programmatic` way, as suggested by Adrian Larson.

2) Query using `GROUP BY aggregate` function. I have shown like below, you need to add all your custom object shown in your posts.

[image]

Possible duplicates of the [How to select Unique values in SOQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23846/how-to-select-unique-values-in-soql) . [How to get unique values of two fields in one SOQL?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133835/how-to-get-unique-values-of-two-fields-in-one-soql).

Comment: My understanding is - OP wants to get the Id of Opportunity which has greatest value in Number_of_Units__c  field. Example if an Account A1 has O1,O2,O3 as its opportunity. OP wants to get the Opportunity that has highest value in Number_of_Units__c for A1. Similarly for each account.

Comment: yes and finally i need to display order by  Number_of_Units__c will you please guide me @SfdcBat

Comment: @Pavantej Please check Santanu's anwer. Hope it gives you the solution